# msdeploy is taking too long from command line and less time using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, iis, deployment, msdeploy, webdeploy

I am configuring my deployment using msdeploy(Web Deploy 3). When I use the Visual Studio the process of publication is pretty fast but when I use the command line it is taking too long.

The command I am using is:

```
msdeploy  -verb:sync 
          -source:contentPath=C:\Source\Project 
          -dest:contentPath=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Project,
           computerName=https://ServerName:8172/msdeploy.axd,
           authType=Basic,
           username=administrator,
           password=password, -allowUntrusted
```

**The msdeploy command was typed in multiple lines in order to provide a more easy and clear lecture**

Do I need to setup anything else in order to provide a more faster deployment process?

Answer (score 1):

This may be because MSDeploy defaults to a timestamp based file comparison.  It could be faster from VS because you have already deployed from there and the timestamps are the same.  Versus from the commandline where you are using a different source with different timestamps?

You can try changing MSDeploy to use a checksum file comparison instead using the `-useCheckSum` flag:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:contentPath="C:\Test1" -dest:contentPath="C:\Test2" -usechecksum
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089(v=ws.10).aspx

This blog post has more details about the MSDeploy file comparison:

http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/06/03/webdeploymsdeploy-quick-tip-only-deploy-changed-files/

Comment: Note: For large binaries, the time it takes to calculate the checksums might even make it slower.